# Text not showing after printing UTF-8 in C

Tags: c, windows, algorithm, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to print some UTF-8 text on my program. It doesn't show up when I do the normal print function, but it did work after I used `#include<fcntl.h>`, `#include <io.h>`, `setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`, and turning `printf` to `wprintf`. However, after I used those lines mentioned above, it made all of my normal print lines invisible, and only the UTF-8 texts visible. How do i fix this?

Here's my code:

```c
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); 

wprintf(L"░██████╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░████████╗██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░░██║██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║░░░██║░░░  ╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║░░░██║░░░  ░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"██████╔╝░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║░░░██║░░░  ░░╚██╔╝░░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"░██████╗██╗░░░██╗░██████╗████████╗███████╗███╗░░░███╗\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"██╔════╝╚██╗░██╔╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝████╗░████║\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"╚█████╗░░╚████╔╝░╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░█████╗░░██╔████╔██║\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"░╚═══██╗░░╚██╔╝░░░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░██║╚██╔╝██║\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██████╔╝░░░██║░░░███████╗██║░╚═╝░██║\n");printf("\n");
wprintf(L"╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝\n");printf("\n"); 


printf("THIS BECOMES INVISIBLE");
printf("how do i make it visible???");

    return;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the original mode when you change it, flush and restore the mode to switch back. You can only use wide stdout functions in _O_U16TEXT mode.  See the two cautions in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-160):

> Unicode mode is for wide print functions (for example, `wprintf`) and is
> not supported for narrow print functions. Use of a narrow print
> function on a Unicode mode stream triggers an assert.

and:

> If you write data to a file stream, explicitly flush the code by using
> `fflush` before you use `_setmode` to change the mode. If you do not flush
> the code, you might get unexpected behavior. If you have not written
> data to the stream, you do not have to flush the code.

```cpp
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    auto old_mode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    wprintf(L"░██████╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░████████╗██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░\n");
    wprintf(L"██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░░██║██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░\n");
    wprintf(L"╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║░░░██║░░░  ╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░\n");
    wprintf(L"░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║░░░██║░░░  ░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗\n");
    wprintf(L"██████╔╝░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║░░░██║░░░  ░░╚██╔╝░░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝\n");
    wprintf(L"╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░\n");
    wprintf(L"░██████╗██╗░░░██╗░██████╗████████╗███████╗███╗░░░███╗\n");
    wprintf(L"██╔════╝╚██╗░██╔╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝████╗░████║\n");
    wprintf(L"╚█████╗░░╚████╔╝░╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░█████╗░░██╔████╔██║\n");
    wprintf(L"░╚═══██╗░░╚██╔╝░░░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░██║╚██╔╝██║\n");
    wprintf(L"██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██████╔╝░░░██║░░░███████╗██║░╚═╝░██║\n");
    wprintf(L"╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝\n");

    fflush(stdout);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), old_mode);
    printf("This is no longer invisible\n");
}
```

Output:

```
░██████╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░████████╗██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░
██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░░██║██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░
╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║░░░██║░░░  ╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░
░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║░░░██║░░░  ░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗
██████╔╝░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║░░░██║░░░  ░░╚██╔╝░░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝
╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░
░██████╗██╗░░░██╗░██████╗████████╗███████╗███╗░░░███╗
██╔════╝╚██╗░██╔╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝████╗░████║
╚█████╗░░╚████╔╝░╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░█████╗░░██╔████╔██║
░╚═══██╗░░╚██╔╝░░░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░██║╚██╔╝██║
██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██████╔╝░░░██║░░░███████╗██║░╚═╝░██║
╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝
This is no longer invisible
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR!!!!!!!!! IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot easily mix `wprintf()` with `printf()`:

> Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream. Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide` function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream. (A successful call to `freopen` removes any orientation.)
> C2x § 7.21.2 4

Comment: Can I revert it back to normal once the UTF-8 text has been displayed, so that I can use the normal `printf()` again? Or perhaps, could you please recommend me a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think here your solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("░██████╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░████████╗██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░\n");
    printf("██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░░██║██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░\n");
    printf("╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║░░░██║░░░  ╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░\n");
    printf("░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║░░░██║░░░  ░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗\n");
    printf("██████╔╝░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║░░░██║░░░  ░░╚██╔╝░░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝\n");
    printf("╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░\n");
    printf("░██████╗██╗░░░██╗░██████╗████████╗███████╗███╗░░░███╗\n");
    printf("██╔════╝╚██╗░██╔╝██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝████╗░████║\n");
    printf("╚█████╗░░╚████╔╝░╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░█████╗░░██╔████╔██║\n");
    printf("░╚═══██╗░░╚██╔╝░░░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░██║╚██╔╝██║\n");
    printf("██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██████╔╝░░░██║░░░███████╗██║░╚═╝░██║\n");
    printf("╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝\n"); 
    
    printf("THIS BECOMES INVISIBLE\n");
    printf("how do i make it visible???\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
░██████╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░████████╗██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░
██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░░██║██╔��═██╗╚══██╔══╝██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░
╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║░░░██║░░░  ╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░
░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚██��█║░░░██║░░░  ░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║░░�██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗
██████╔╝░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║░░░██║░░░  ░░╚██╔╝��░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║██║░╚███║╚��█████╔╝
╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚═════╝░�══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░
░██████╗██╗░░░██╗░████��█╗████████╗███████╗███╗░░░███╗
�█╔════╝╚██╗░██╔╝██╔════╝╚══██╔═�╝██╔════╝████╗░████║
╚█████╗░░╚████╔╝░╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░█████╗░░██╔████╔██║
░╚═══██╗░░╚██╔╝░░░╚══��██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░██║╚██╔╝██║
██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██████╔╝░░░██║�░░███████╗██║░╚═╝░██║
╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝
THIS BECOMES INVISIBLE
how do i make it visible???
```

Comment: Does not work on Windows.  That's why non_standard `_setmode` is required for OP.