# C++ std::printf formatting breaks with cyrillic alphabet

Tags: c++, output, printf

I've noticed somewhat of an unexpected behavior when using `std::printf()` with max field length specifiers like `%10ls` in conjuction with `wchar_t` (for cyrillic text).

Code example I use:

```
void printHeader() {
    printDelim();
    std::printf("\n|%15ls|%15ls|%15ls|%15ls|%15ls|", L"Имя", L"Континент", L"Длина", L"Глубина", L"Приток");
}
```

Simple function that prints delimiter (bunch of "-") and *should be* printing formatted line of titles (in Russian) separated by "|". So each field will be max 15 chars long and look pretty.

Actual output: `|         Имя|Континент|     Длина|Глубина| Приток |`

Notice:

1. Locale is set like this `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` and Russian is present there.
2. If parameters passed to `printf()` are in English - works fine.
3. Just in case - output of the `setlocale()`:

```
Locale: LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

4. Also tried it with `std::wprintf()`, but it does not print anything at all.
5. `std::printf()` with `%15s` and same strings without `L` prefix prints in the same "broken length" manner **and** cyrillic strings are correct.

I'm extremely curious why this happens with `wchar_t`.

P.S. - I'm aware that this code is almost literally C in C++, which is a bad idea and practice. Unfortunately it is required to do so in this case.

Comment: Why is C bad practice? Over 80% of all packages in a typical datacenter server is written in C.

Comment: @NoleKsum I don't mean that C is bad. I love it. I just mean wouldn't it be an easier and cleaner way to just use std::format or external lib (that will be wrapping C funcs) and call it a day?

Comment: @Danny `std::format` is only available on trunk from gcc and clang at this time. I don't think any releases have it. That said, you could use `boost::format` instead. But `printf` is industry standard.

Comment: It looks like it's writing 15 bytes: 9 spaces + 3 wchar_ts is 9+3*2=15 bytes for the first field. What was your `wprintf` call? Replacing it like `std::wprintf(L"\n|%15ls...` seemed to work fine

Comment: @Artyer Tried `std::wprintf(L"\n...")` right now again. Output - noting. Not even an empty line - just acts like empty string.

Comment: The field widths are counts of bytes, the UTF-8 sequences for each Cyrillic character takes more than one byte.

Comment: Are you on Windows perhaps?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69650866/235698 for a Windows solution, if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at cppreference.com's [description of the `%ls` format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), because it explains one part of what's happening here in a very clear way:

> If the l specifier is used, the argument must be a pointer to the initial element of an array of wchar_t, which is converted to char array as if by a call to wcrtomb with zero-initialized conversion state.

The key take-away is that `%ls` converts the `wchar_t` string to plain, narrow characters, as the first order of business. Basically, `std::printf` works with non-wide "characters", and allegedly-wide character strings get converted to non-wide "character" strings, before anything else happens.

Now that the input's domain consists of non-wide characters we make further progress:

Referencing "characters" in the context of the ***width*** specifier: it's really specifying the number of ***bytes***. 15 bytes. That's what it really means:

```
Имя
```

This is not three "characters", as far as `printf` is concerned. This is a six character sequence, here they are: `d0 98 d0 bc d1 8f`.

> Just in case - output of the setlocale():
>
> Locale: LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 ...

Your system uses UTF-8 encoding, which uses more than one byte to encode non-Latin characters.

`printf` is a little bit dumb. It doesn't know anything about your locale, or your encoding. Every reference to character counts and field widths, in `printf`'s documentation really means bytes. `%15s`, or `%15ls`, really means not 15 characters, but 15 bytes, to format here. So, it counts off 15 bytes, and spits them out. But, when interpreted as UTF-8 characters, these bytes don't really take up 15 characters on the screen.

Before Unicode, before the modern world with many alphabets, funny-looking characters, there was only the Latin alphabet, and characters and bytes were pretty much the same thing, and `printf`'s documentation harkens back to that era. This is not true any more, but `printf` is still living in the past.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you for such detailed answer!